# Fastest free Python library to read a CSV file with 1~3 columns of numbers

Tags: gratis, library, python, csv, performance

I am looking for the fastest Python library to read a CSV file (if that matters, 1 or 3 columns, all integers or floats, [example](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B4y6Mj_UZoTEMTVZdFp2NHpHdjQ/edit?usp=sharing)) into a Python array (or some object that I can access in a similar fashion, with a similar access time). It should be free, work on Windows 7 and Ubuntu 12.04, and with Python 2.7 x64.

CSV with 1 column:

```
350
750
252
138
125
125
125
112
95
196
105
101
101
101
102
101
101
102
202
104
```

CSV with 3 columns:

```
9,52,1
52,91,0
91,135,0
135,174,0
174,218,0
218,260,0
260,301,0
301,341,0
341,383,0
383,423,0
423,466,0
466,503,0
503,547,0
547,583,0
583,629,0
629,667,0
667,713,0
713,754,0
754,796,0
796,839,1
```

Comment: Coincidentally, there is a very similar question posted 2 hours ago on Super User: http://superuser.com/q/775893/137286 The first answer suggests a fast library.

Comment: Have you tested with fastcsv, as I suggested below, lately? I would be very interested to hear how it performs with your data. Cheers, Daniel

Answer (score 33, accepted):

So I eventually wrote a small benchmark using the libraries Steve Barnes had pointed at. I had found the same when looking for it as I was writing the question so I guess that's the main ones. Some other ideas that haven't tried yet: [HDF5 for Python](http://docs.h5py.org/), [PyTables](http://www.pytables.org/), [IOPro](https://store.continuum.io/cshop/iopro/) (non-free).

In short, `pandas.io.parsers.read_csv` beats everybody else, NumPy's `loadtxt` is impressively slow and NumPy's `from_file` and `load` impressively fast.

[Data](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B4y6Mj_UZoTEUUliZWhLRjNHS0k/view?usp=sharing&resourcekey=0-J3RLs0it8NrxRL32VoKhuQ) (I should have generated them in the benchmark but I am running out of time right now)

Code:

```
import csv
import os
import cProfile
import time
import numpy
import pandas
import warnings

# Make sure those files in the same folder as benchmark_python.py
# As the name indicates:
# - '1col.csv' is a CSV file with 1 column
# - '3col.csv' is a CSV file with 3 column
filename1 = '1col.csv'
filename3 = '3col.csv'
csv_delimiter = ' '
debug = False

def open_with_python_csv(filename):
    '''
    https://docs.python.org/2/library/csv.html
    '''
    data =[]
    with open(filename, 'rb') as csvfile:
        csvreader = csv.reader(csvfile, delimiter=csv_delimiter, quotechar='|')
        for row in csvreader:
            data.append(row)    
    return data

def open_with_python_csv_cast_as_float(filename):
    '''
    https://docs.python.org/2/library/csv.html
    '''
    data =[]
    with open(filename, 'rb') as csvfile:
        csvreader = csv.reader(csvfile, delimiter=csv_delimiter, quotechar='|')
        for row in csvreader:
            data.append(map(float, row))    
    return data

def open_with_python_csv_list(filename):
    '''
    https://docs.python.org/2/library/csv.html
    '''
    data =[]
    with open(filename, 'rb') as csvfile:
        csvreader = csv.reader(csvfile, delimiter=csv_delimiter, quotechar='|')
        data = list(csvreader)    
    return data


def open_with_numpy_loadtxt(filename):
    '''
    http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4315506/load-csv-into-2d-matrix-with-numpy-for-plotting
    '''
    data = numpy.loadtxt(open(filename,'rb'),delimiter=csv_delimiter,skiprows=0)
    return data

def open_with_pandas_read_csv(filename):
    df = pandas.read_csv(filename, sep=csv_delimiter)
    data = df.values
    return data    


def benchmark(function_name):  
    start_time = time.clock()
    data = function_name(filename1)       
    if debug: print data[0] 
    data = function_name(filename3)
    if debug: print data[0]
    print function_name.__name__ + ': ' + str(time.clock() - start_time), "seconds"


def benchmark_numpy_fromfile():
    '''
    http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.fromfile.html
    Do not rely on the combination of tofile and fromfile for data storage, 
    as the binary files generated are are not platform independent.
    In particular, no byte-order or data-type information is saved.
    Data can be stored in the platform independent .npy format using
    save and load instead.
    
    Note that fromfile will create a one-dimensional array containing your data,
    so you might need to reshape it afterward.
    '''
    #ignore the 'tmpnam is a potential security risk to your program' warning
    with warnings.catch_warnings():
        warnings.simplefilter('ignore', RuntimeWarning)
        fname1 = os.tmpnam()
        fname3 = os.tmpnam()
        
    data = open_with_numpy_loadtxt(filename1)
    if debug: print data[0]
    data.tofile(fname1)
    data = open_with_numpy_loadtxt(filename3)
    if debug: print data[0]
    data.tofile(fname3)
    if debug: print data.shape
    fname3shape = data.shape
    start_time = time.clock()
    data = numpy.fromfile(fname1, dtype=numpy.float64) # you might need to switch to float32. List of types: http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/arrays.dtypes.html
    if debug: print len(data), data[0], data.shape
    data = numpy.fromfile(fname3, dtype=numpy.float64)
    data = data.reshape(fname3shape)
    if debug: print len(data), data[0], data.shape    
    print 'Numpy fromfile: ' + str(time.clock() - start_time), "seconds"

def benchmark_numpy_save_load():
    '''
    http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.fromfile.html
    Do not rely on the combination of tofile and fromfile for data storage, 
    as the binary files generated are are not platform independent.
    In particular, no byte-order or data-type information is saved.
    Data can be stored in the platform independent .npy format using
    save and load instead.
    
    Note that fromfile will create a one-dimensional array containing your data,
    so you might need to reshape it afterward.
    '''
    #ignore the 'tmpnam is a potential security risk to your program' warning
    with warnings.catch_warnings():
        warnings.simplefilter('ignore', RuntimeWarning)
        fname1 = os.tmpnam()
        fname3 = os.tmpnam()
        
    data = open_with_numpy_loadtxt(filename1)
    if debug: print data[0]    
    numpy.save(fname1, data)    
    data = open_with_numpy_loadtxt(filename3)
    if debug: print data[0]    
    numpy.save(fname3, data)    
    if debug: print data.shape
    fname3shape = data.shape
    start_time = time.clock()
    data = numpy.load(fname1 + '.npy')
    if debug: print len(data), data[0], data.shape
    data = numpy.load(fname3 + '.npy')
    #data = data.reshape(fname3shape)
    if debug: print len(data), data[0], data.shape    
    print 'Numpy load: ' + str(time.clock() - start_time), "seconds"


def main():
    number_of_runs = 20
    results = []
    
    benchmark_functions = ['benchmark(open_with_python_csv)', 
                           'benchmark(open_with_python_csv_list)',
                           'benchmark(open_with_python_csv_cast_as_float)',
                           'benchmark(open_with_numpy_loadtxt)',
                           'benchmark(open_with_pandas_read_csv)',
                           'benchmark_numpy_fromfile()',
                           'benchmark_numpy_save_load()']
    # Compute benchmark
    for run_number in range(number_of_runs):
        run_results = []
        for benchmark_function in benchmark_functions:
            run_results.append(eval(benchmark_function))
            results.append(run_results)
        
    # Display benchmark's results
    print results
    results = numpy.array(results)
    numpy.set_printoptions(precision=10) # http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2891790/pretty-printing-of-numpy-array
    numpy.set_printoptions(suppress=True)  # suppress suppresses the use of scientific notation for small numbers:
    print numpy.mean(results, axis=0)
    print numpy.std(results, axis=0)    
    
    #Another library, but not free: https://store.continuum.io/cshop/iopro/

if __name__ == "__main__":
    #cProfile.run('main()') # if you want to do some profiling
    main()
```

---

### Windows 7:

Output:

```
open_with_python_csv: 1.57318865672 seconds
open_with_python_csv_list: 1.35567931732 seconds
open_with_python_csv_cast_as_float: 3.0801260484 seconds
open_with_numpy_loadtxt: 14.4942111801 seconds
open_with_pandas_read_csv: 0.371965476805 seconds
Numpy fromfile: 0.0130216095713 seconds
Numpy load: 0.0245501650124 seconds
```

To install all libraries: [Unofficial Windows Binaries for Python Extension Packages](http://www.lfd.uci.edu/%7Egohlke/pythonlibs/)

Windows configuration:

- Windows 7 SP1 x64 Ultimate
- Python 2.7.6 x64
- NumPy 1.7.1 (`import numpy; numpy.version.version`)
- Pandas 0.13.1 (`import pandas as pd; pd.__version__`)
- [MSI Computer Corp. Notebook Computer GE70 0ND-033US;9S7-175611-033](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B0082JFD1W) (with SSD Crucial M5)

---

### Ubuntu 12.04:

Output:

```
open_with_python_csv: 1.93 seconds
open_with_python_csv_list: 1.52 seconds
open_with_python_csv_cast_as_float: 3.19 seconds
open_with_numpy_loadtxt: 7.47 seconds
open_with_pandas_read_csv: 0.35 seconds
Numpy fromfile: 0.01 seconds
Numpy load: 0.02 seconds
```

To install all libraries:

```
sudo apt-get install python-pip
sudo pip install numpy
sudo pip install pandas
```

If libraries are already installed but need to be upgraded:

```
sudo apt-get install python-pip
sudo pip install numpy --upgrade
sudo pip install pandas --upgrade
```

Ubuntu configuration:

- Ubuntu 12.04 x64
- Python 2.7.3
- NumPy 1.8.1 (`import numpy; numpy.version.version`)
- Pandas 0.14.0 (`import pandas as pd; pd.__version__`)

---

Obviously feel free to improve the benchmark by commenting/editing/etc, I'm sure about that there are plenty of things to enhance:

- Making sure that the current loading functions are well optimized
- Try new functions / libraries such as [HDF5 for Python](http://docs.h5py.org/), [PyTables](http://www.pytables.org/), [IOPro](https://store.continuum.io/cshop/iopro/) (non-free).
- Generate the CSV in the benchmark (so that one doesn't have to download the CSV files)

Comment: An interesting comparison of results.

Comment: you saved me from the dark and lonely world of `numpy.loadtxt`

Comment: Great answer. FYI I ran your benchmark on a 2gB cvs file:                                       open_with_python_csv: 153.789445 seconds
open_with_python_csv_list: 146.709768 seconds
open_with_python_csv_cast_as_float: 86.957046 seconds
open_with_numpy_loadtxt: 157.669637 seconds
open_with_pandas_read_csv: 77.612668 seconds

Comment: This is great and I've learned a lot this evening from this post.  However your `np.fromfile` seems *awfully* fast.  What I found in my tests is that it just works on the first line, so to do the whole file you have to do a loop which slows things down again to 60s for my 20k line csv file, vs. 0.75s for Pandas.  Are you reading the entire file with `np.fromfile`?  I was also able to use `np.fromstring` by loading the entire csv file, `replace`ing the `'\n` with `''` then running `np.fromstring`.  The string manipulations were fast, but converting to numbers was slow.  This method took 2.6s.

Comment: Trying this in 2018 on windows 10 with python 2.7.13 with a 100000 row file with 19 columns just testing the open_with_python_csv, open_with_python_csv_list and open_with_pandas_read_csv and the pandas method is not faster. Built in csv means are ~0.35 and pandas ~0.43.

Comment: Just as a note, pandas.read_csv by default does a ton of random processing such as replacing string values like "N/A" with nulls and converting strings that *kinda* look like numbers to ints producing a lot of potential data loss (bit me already).

Answer (score 8):

I would like to contribute another library here, that I stumbled over looking for similar question. I tested it with Franck Dernoncourts benchmark code and it beats Pythons standard csv and Pandas by miles. I could not test with numpy, since i tested with a 24.000 line csv with number and string values.

This speedy library is actually based on the default csv implementation, just using *TextIO* which makes it faster **AND** handles unicode strings correctly.

It is named [fastcsv](https://github.com/draftcode/fastcsv) and was developed by Masaya Suzuki. You can close it in GitHub or use Pypi to install. Simplest is:

```
pip install fastcsv
```

On http://pythonhosted.org/fastcsv/ you can see more Benchmark results, but for just reading csv let me repeat their results here:

[image: Reading Benchmark using fastcsv]

Would be interesting to know, how this performs with your data.

Comment: _"TLDR: This is deprecated. Use Python3 and the standard csv module. So, I don't recommend using this library."_ - Author's note?

Comment: @SebastianPalma Original question specifies python 2.7

Comment: This answer doesn't age well. Project is deprecated and standard Python3 csv library is fast again.

Answer (score 5):

You have a wide choice depending on data size and complexity and what you are going to do with the resulting data:

1. The `csv` library that comes with Python by default.
2. NumPy - `numpy.from_file` [function](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.fromfile.html) - Reads to a NumPy array so it is very powerful.
3. Pandas - `pandas.io.parsers.read_csv` [function](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.io.parsers.read_csv.html) - reads to a pandas data frame, is very powerful, and can handle huge data sets.

The first will probably be faster to import while the others are more powerful. All are free & cross platform. The first is already part of your Python installation if you have a default one.

Answer (score 1):

There is a new `pydatatable` package which has very fast csv reader based on R data.table `fread` implementation.
Read more at https://github.com/h2oai/datatable
If you want to have pandas object loaded you can simply run

```
pandas_dataframe = dt.fread(srcfile).to_pandas()
```

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest keeping an eye out for pandas official documentation on [IO](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/io.html). One's option keeps changing based on the development cycle and new formats get added all time. They also publish the benchmark.

Answer (score 0):

There is a new Python package for data mining which names [DaPy](https://dapy.kitgram.cn). Which has a simple I/O API and fast enough for you. According to the performance test from the author, DaPy spent 12.5 seconds on loading a csv file with more than 2 million records, while pandas spent 4 seconds. However, DaPy is based on some python native data structures and more easily to use.

```
cmd: pip install DaPy 
>>> import DaPy as dp
>>> data = dp.read('file.csv')
>>> data.show()
```